# Passing and adding parameters through random url redirection

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, url-parameters

I'm preparing a study for my Ph.D. in which I need to randomly redirect participants to webpages, keeping and adding parameters to the url to see at the end which webpages they've visited. But, I'm a psychologist, so css & javascript are quite difficult for me.

Here's how my study will be:

1. I publish a shorten link on social medias which *randomly* redirects to a webpage (point 2 or point 3).
2. A short message with a link that *randomly* redirects to one of the stage 3 webpages.
3. At the end of the webpage, there's a link that redirects to my unique form (Typeform).

→  Typeform questionnaire can read and collect URL parameters so I know who read what pages on stages 2 and 3, from what social media they come (stage 1).

**My question is:** how do I create scripts that will **randomly redirect** and **pass** & **add** parameters to the URL, depending on the webpages participants will see?

**Example:**
**1**. I see the link on twitter, I click on it.
 → *Script randomly redirects me to http://example.com/stage2/ and adds ?source=twitter*
**2**. I read that second page and click on the link it provides
→ *Script randomly redirects me to http://example.com/stage3/?source=twitter and adds &stage2=theguysawstage2*
**3**. I read that third page and click on the final link to get to the typeform.
→ *Script redirects me to [http://my.typeform.com/?source=twitter&stage2=theguysawstage2&stage3=theguysawstage3](http://my.typeform.com/?source=twitter&stage2=theguysawstage2&stage3=theguysawstage3_)*

Thanks a lot to whoever will help!
DimNC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit] **Here's the answer:**

```
$links[] = 'http://url.com/abc?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'&newparameter1=foo&newparameter2=bar';
```

`.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].` will get the current parameters & their values. You just have to insert it where you want in the redirected url, and add the new parameters.

Be careful though, the first parameter shall be preceded by a  question mark: `?firstparameter=foo&secondparameter=bar`.

[Previous post:]

@PVL, I already have that in a .php for random redirection:

```
$links = array();  
$links[] = 'http://facebook.com';  
$links[] = 'http://google.com';  
$links[] = 'http://stackoverflow.com';

shuffle($links);

$i= rand(0, (count($links) - 1));  
$link   = $links[$i];

header("Location: {$link}");
exit;
```

Comment: I think shuffle is redundant in your code. I never tried this. So I can't give you an exact answer since it would be try and error for me too if I would implement this. As for redirecting by ?webpage=facebook you first use if(isset($_GET["webpage"])){switch($_GET["webpage"]){ then case "facebook": then redirect to facebook break; }}. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of some random links that you are redirected too.
First you get random number between 0-2. Then you push your links in array. They have index between 0-2. For example facebook is nr 0, google is nr 1. You can also see random number in console.

```
   var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 0); 
   var linkArray = new Array();
   linkArray.push("https://www.facebook.com/");
   linkArray.push("https://www.google.com/");
   linkArray.push("http://stackoverflow.com");  
   window.location = linkArray[random];
   console.log(random);
```